# Time series dataframe. Plot two distinct time ranges with a relative starting point

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, time-series

I have a dataframe with a time series (daily prices of a single stock). I want to take two distinct time ranges and overlay them on plot with a relative starting point of 0 instead of a date.

In the example below, if I plot 1962 and 2018, it uses the date as the x axis instead of a relative starting point.

```
SPY = pd.read_csv('GSPC.csv', parse_dates=['dDate'], index_col='dDate')

SPY1962 = SPY['1962']
SPY2018 = SPY['2018']

firstprice62 = SPY1962['nAdjClose'].iloc[0]
firstprice18 = SPY2018['nAdjClose'].iloc[0]

normal62 = SPY1962['nAdjClose'].div(firstprice62).mul(100)
normal18 = SPY2018['nAdjClose'].div(firstprice18).mul(100)
```

[A picture of what I'm trying to accomplish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xdgyg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
normal18 = normal18.reset_index()
normal62 = normal62.reset_index()

normal62['nAdjClose'].plot()
normal18['nAdjClose'].plot()

plt.show()
```